# Navigating Between HTML Windows

Tags: javascript, html

and thanks for taking a look at this seemingly simple question.

The scenario is as follows: I have a website Homepage named 'welcome.html'. From here users can select from a list of URLs and on clicking on the URL a simple Javascript function is called which opens a new Window.

Once the user has finished in the newly opened Window I want them to click on a button which calls a Javascript function to return them to the Homepage. It seems so simple.

However, if the Homepage Window is still open I want to return to this and not open another new Window displaying the Homepage. If the Homepage Window has been closed then I want a new Window to open displaying the Homepage.

I would be very grateful for some guidance here as I can't seem to get it to work.

Regards

Chris

Comment: A UI that opens up all kinds of windows is not very friendly - consider a different design.

Comment: You should be able to do this by just keeping track of window names.  But don't do it.  You can't control how browsers show new windows, or even if they show windows at all (using tabs instead, in other words). You can't control window focus policy much either. Overall it's just not a good idea to open lots of new windows for people.

Comment: Listen to @Oded, for he speaks the truth.

Comment: <a> elements can have target attribute, and _parent is one of them. Check that, maybe JS gives you some help there. I doubt it though. Especially that you can control the browsers tabs/windows like that.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it is not the greatest design.  However, I've run into scenarios like this in the past, where the business logic stipulates that a new window must be opened and there is no ability to change that.

As Pointy said, the biggest thing is just to keep track of the windows opened, and if you need some further help, perhaps this may help:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

But if possible, I would consider a different design (ask here if you need help implementing it!)

Comment: Thank you, and everyone else, for your thoughts. I know it's not a good pattern but I have to tidy up the current structure before I direct all content into the same Window. I've developed a solution and I will share it below in an answer to myself.

Answer (score 1):

and thank you everyone who went to the trouble of sharing their thoughts.

I solved the problem in the following way:

When navigating from the Homepage to the new Window the following Javascript is used to open a new Window:

```
function popupFull(url)

// For explanation of this code see: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

// Note: If fullscreen = 1 you can't see the menubar, toolbar, status etc.
// It is advisable to have no spaces around the commas in the parameters.

{
    //alert("Opening: " + url)

    // Prepare the parameter string
    params = 'width='+screen.width;
    params += ',height='+screen.height;
    params += ',top=0,left=0';
    params += ',fullscreen=0';
    params += ',menubar=0';
    params += ',toolbar=0';
    params += ',directories=0';
    params += ',status=0';
    params += ',scrollbars=0';
    params += ',resizable=1';

    // Open a new window.
    newWin=window.open(url, "fullWindow", params);

    // If the current Window is in focus, switch focus to the new Window.
    if (window.focus)
    {
        newWin.focus()
    }

    // Return the new Window object reference.
    return newWin;
}
```

So the new Window can be opened and I have left the Homepage Window open but out of focus behind the new Window.

In the new Window there is a 'Menu' button. Clicking on this calls the following Javascript function:

```
function openMenu(winURL, winName, winFeatures)
{
// Create a reference of the Window which opened this Window. This should be
// the Main Menu Window.
var winObj=window.opener;

var menuOuterWidth = 1080;
var menuOuterHeight = 896;

var menuInnerWidth = 1068;
var menuInnerHeight = 767;

var menuX = (screen.width - menuOuterWidth) / 2;
var menuY = (screen.height - menuOuterHeight) / 2;

// Prepare the parameter string for re-opening the Menu
params = 'width='+menuInnerWidth;
params += ',height='+menuInnerHeight;
params += ',top='+menuY+',left='+menuX;
params += ',fullscreen=0';
params += ',menubar=1';
params += ',toolbar=1';
params += ',status=1';
params += ',scrollbars=1';
params += ',location=1';
params += ',resizable=1';

try
{
    // Check to see if the window reference already exists.
    if (winObj)
    {
        // Check to see if the Menu window is closed.
        if (winObj.closed)
        {
            // The Menu window is closed.
            // Open the Menu Window.
            winObj = window.open(winURL, winName, params);

            // Close this Course Window.
            window.close();

            // Return the Menu Window object reference should the caller want it.
            return winObj;
        }
        else
        {
            // The Menu Window has not been closed. Set the Window's size and position.
            // Note: When resizing the outerWidth/outerHeight value has to be passed.
            winObj.window.resizeTo(menuOuterWidth, menuOuterHeight);
            winObj.window.moveTo(menuX, menuY);

            // Bring it into focus (bring to front). 
            winObj.focus();

            // Close this Course Window.
            window.close();

            // Return the Menu Window object reference should the caller want it.
            return winObj;
        }
    }

    else

    {

        // The winObj object does not exist. Open the Menu.
        winObj = window.open(winURL, winName, params);

        // Close this Course Window.
        window.close();

        // Return the Menu Window object reference should the caller want it.
        return winObj;
    }
}

catch(err)
{
    txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
    txt+="Error description: " + err.description + "\n\n";
    txt+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
    //alert(txt);

    // When IE6 tries to obtain the winObj.closed property, when the window is closed, it can cause
    // an error "Permission Denied". This error is caught here. Open the Menu.

    // Open the Menu Window.
    winObj = window.open(winURL, winName, params);

    // Close this Course Window.
    window.close();

    // Return the Menu Window object reference should the caller want it.
    return winObj;
}
```

}

The comments should explain everything. The key is to get a reference to the Homepage Window where we started. (`var winObj=window.opener;`).

What caused me such a headache was that if I opened the new Window (using IE6), switched back to the Homepage and closed the Homepage Window, and then in the new Window clicked on the 'Menu' button nothing happened! I tried everything and then, after a cup of tea, realised that I would never write code in any application I was developing without any form of error capture. I added a Try, Catch statement and reported the error in an 'alert'. I got a 'Permission Denied' error.

After a lot of reading I figured I couldn't eliminate the error I would simply handle the error as elegantly as I could. This resulted in the code above.

It works a treat and I hope this helps someone.